# Expresión regular que encuentre 3 o mas vocales (la vocal debe de ser la misma) repetidas en una misma palabra

Tags: python-3.x, regex

no tengo experiencia con expresiones regulares, he estado tratando de resolver un problema, necesito encontrar palabras que contengan 3 o mas vocales que se repitan, (La vocal debe de ser la misma):
Se debería de hacer match con las siguientes palabras:
cazadora, pelele, aa3ab, etc.

La expresión regular que tengo funciona bien en [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

El problema es que necesito que funcione en python, pero no retorna los match que espero.

La expresión regular que tengo es esta:
`([^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[\w]*)|([^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[\w]*)|([^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[\w]*)|([^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[\w]*)|([^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[\w]*)`

En python la salida es la siguiente:

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':

    expresion = r"([^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[^aA\s\n]*(a|A)[\w]*)|([^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[^eE\s\n]*(e|E)[\w]*)|([^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[^iI\s\n]*(i|I)[\w]*)|([^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[^oO\s\n]*(o|O)[\w]*)|([^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[^uU\s\n]*(u|U)[\w]*)"

    encontrado = re.findall(expresion, "La cazadora vende las pieles para pelele")

    print(encontrado)
```

Salida:

```
[('cazadora', 'a', 'a', 'a', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''), ('', '', '', '', 'pelele', 'e', 'e', 'e', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')]
```

Comment: ¿Y lo tienes que resolver con expresiones regulares si o si?

Answer (score 2):

La expresión regular que necesitas es

```
r"([aeiou]).*\1.*\1"
```

que lee así:

- `([aeiou])` buscar y capturar una vocal (grupo captura #1),
- `.*` seguida de cero o más caracteres cualquiera,
- `\1` seguida de la misma vocal encontrada y capturada en grupo #1,
- `.*` seguida de cero o más caracteres cualquiera,
- `\1` seguida de la misma vocal encontrada y capturada en grupo #1.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"([aeiou]).*\1.*\1", re.IGNORECASE)

tests = "La cazadora vende las pieles para pelele".split()

for test in tests:
    m = patron.findall(test)
    if m:
        print(f"Vocal repetida en {test} es {m[0]}")
```

produce:

```
Vocal repetida en cazadora es a
Vocal repetida en pelele es e

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `r"([aeiou])[^ ]*\1[^ ]*\1"` sería una opción que no requiere el `split()`

Comment: @Emeeus. El objeto del `split` es procesar cada palabra por separado. No puedes reasignar `\1` dentro de expresión regular, por lo que estas expresiones sólo reconocen **una** repetición dentro de la cadena. El patrón propuesto no funciona con el texto del OP.

Comment: Borré el ejemplo porque sucedía lo mismo, tanto tu expresión, como la que indiqué no sirven para encontrar las 2 repeticiones en un string del tipo "aaooao", de hecho ninguna va a servir, hay que ordenar si o si.

Comment: Use `split` para reducir el problema. Por otra parte, no creo que haya una palabra en castellano con dos letras repetidas tres veces cada una. De todas maneras, las exp. reg. propuestas son mucho más simples que las del OP.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que ninguna expresión regular va a encontrar la repetición de "a" y al mismo tiempo "o" en un string del tipo "aaooao" a menos que ordenenemos el string. Por ello, ordenando las palabras en el ejemplo de @CandidMoe, y usando `r"(([aeiou])\2\2)+"` funcionaría para encontrar todo:

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(([aeiou])\2\2)+", re.IGNORECASE)

tests = "La cazadoraoo vende las pieles para pelele, goooooooool".split()

for  test in tests:
    mt = [m.group(2) for m in patron.finditer(''.join(sorted(test)))]
    if len(mt):
        print("en", test, "estan repetidas 3 o mas veces", mt)
```

La salida es:

```
en cazadoraoo estan repetidas 3 o mas veces ['a', 'o']
en pelele, estan repetidas 3 o mas veces ['e']
en goooooooool estan repetidas 3 o mas veces ['o']
```

Encuentra la "a" y la "o" repetidas en "cazadoraoo" y la "e" repetida en "pelele". Las "o" finales deben matchear una sola vez.

Answer (score 0):

Para *"encontrar palabras que contengan 3 o mas vocales"* *iguales*, se puede utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
(?=\w*([aeiou])\w*\1\w*\1)\w+
```

Utiliza un lookahead para verificar que una palabra cumpla la condición de contener al menos una vocal que aparezca al menos tres veces (la misma) y luego genera una coincidencia con la palabra completa.

Si se esperan caracteres en mayúscula, se debe habilitar *ignorecase*.

Una versión más corta sería: `(?=\w*([aeiou])(\w*\1){2})\w+`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Probar en Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vdevBB/2)